# How to send JSON via POST to flask web service correctly?

Tags: python, flask

I'm trying to send the following JSON data to my flask service

`{'filesIds': ['0698Y00000Rb5vuQAB', '0698Y00000Rb6GsQAJ']}`

but getting wired response: first it's 200, then 400 bad request:

```
Mar 10 02:41:40 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2023:12:41:40 +0000] "POST /parsed-invoice HTTP/1.1" 200 3033 "-" "SFDC-Callout/57.0"
Mar 10 02:41:41 PM  127.0.0.1 - - [10/Mar/2023:12:41:41 +0000] "POST /parsed-invoice HTTP/1.1" 400 167 "-" "SFDC-Callout/57.0"
```

here in flask service i can get the data tho.

```
app.route('/parsed-invoice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_invoice():
    files_ids_jsonified = request.get_json()
    print(f"FILE IDS JSON  {files_ids_jsonified} TYPE {type(files_ids_jsonified)}")
```

out:
`FILE IDS JSON  {'filesIds': ['0698Y00000Rb5vuQAB', '0698Y00000Rb6GsQAJ']} TYPE <class 'dict'>`

I have tried to check if method is post

```
app.route('/parsed-invoice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_invoice():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        files_ids_jsonified = request.get_json()
        print(f"FILE IDS JSON  {files_ids_jsonified} TYPE {type(files_ids_jsonified)}")
```

but still had that issue. I also tried `get_json(force=True)` - it didn't help as well. I also tried to use double quotes and it didn't work.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already received json. The next step you need get filesIds by their key:

```
@app.route('/parsed-invoice', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def parse_invoice():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json()
        files_ids = data.get('filesIds', [])
```